# Npm check which package is required sub package

Tags: javascript, npm

When I'm running `npm install` I'm getting the following error:

> Couldn't find package "getSnapshot-pkg-repo@^1.0.0" required by
>   "conventional-changelog-core@^2.0.11 " on the "npm" registry.

I don't know from where it's coming. I don't specify the `conventional-changelog-core` directly in my `package.json` file which means some other package is requiring it. How can I know what is causing the problem?

Comment: see if you have a `package-lock.json` file generally it contains all the packages and sub packages requirements, if not then I am afraid you will have to check the package.json file for your node modules from your package.json file.

Comment: Thanks! deleted the lock file and it worked.

Comment: great ill post it as an answer for others as well (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have a `package-lock.json` file generally it contains all the packages and sub packages requirements and chances are it might be outdated so just delete the file and try running `npm install` again should work.

If not then I am afraid you will have to check the package.json file for each of your node modules from your package.json file and check the package requiring that particular module and possible find its replacement.